# web app - perform an action 90 seconds after navigating away from the home page

Tags: javascript, java, jquery

I have a java (7) web app (spring mvc).  The business have asked for an action (display a pop up announcement) to take place 90 seconds after the user navigates away from the home page.  The views/pages are all jsp pages and all of them have a header and footer jspf.  There are not too many web pages in the application - maybe about 8 (it being more about the data).

I'm looking for suggestions about the best way to do this!  I'm thinking adding a session date/time value in the unload event and then checking against this value every 4 or 5 seconds (the 90 seconds isn't mission critical!) until I hit 90 seconds.

What strikes me most about this solution is although it probably won't affect the user experience too much it is a bit inefficient as I can't see how I will be able to stop checking the session variable every 5 seconds even once the action has been completed.

Could anyone help me with a better approach ?

Comment: well you can stop checking the session variable once the 90 second mark was hit. set another session variable to false so that a new check wont be made on every new page...

Comment: Nothing yet ?  I have just got the requirement and was really hoping to check my intended approach rather than validate/request any specific code.  I can delete the question if this is not a reasonable question to ask here (?)

Comment: Thanks Alex, that makes sense (should have thought of that!)

Comment: Just start a JavaScript interval that counts for 90 seconds. No session needed.

Comment: Sorry not great on javascript but wouldn't that mean if they reloaded the page, or navigated somewhere else within the 90 seconds they would reset the counter ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Answer is for a server-side Java solution, where you have Push available. Ideal for server-side framework like [Vaadin](http://www.Vaadin.com/) but may be overkill for simple JSP page.

## Executor

Java 5 and later bundles sophisticated classes for scheduling tasks on background threads. These classes implement [`Executor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html).

Specifically, the [`ScheduledExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html). You specify a number such as 90 and a time unit such as Seconds. You pass a [`Callable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) or [`Runnable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) object as the task to be performed. Java handles the rest. You get back a [`ScheduledFuture`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledFuture.html) which you can query for its status if you need to monitor completion.

See the [Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html).

This work happens on a background thread. So your Callable/Runnable needs to reach the main Servlet’s thread and its objects so you must be aware of concurrency issues.

All of this has been covered extensively on StackOverflow. So search for further info.

Comment: Thanks,  I will look at these when I have a minute although I'm hoping it's overkill for my scenario (maybe not though, early stages!).  Again thanks for pointing me at a new thing!

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget: the *current* page has control of the Javascript.  Any pending timeouts are simply discarded when the browser leaves a page.

So the page you go to has be the one with the actual alert.

One way might be for the unload() function of the home page to write something in a cookie or in local-storage that says, "At this specific time [90 seconds in the future], display this message."

Then every page (probably the header of every page) has to look for the something, and if it is there, and the time is still in the future, set a timeout for that many seconds; when the timeout expires, pop up the message and erase the something.

Comment: I don't really want to use cookies before they have accepted their use.  I have been playing with using sessionStorage.  This seems to fit the bill as it self clears on closing the session but constant throughout & is accessible from javascript.  Must admit it's a new one on me though (hadn't considered client javascript, server session issue when I posted the question!).  doesn't need to keep 90 second count across sessions, just checking its not catching casual browsers.  Have I missed something when you recommend local-storage or is it just that I didn't fully describe the scenario ? Thanks